# Visual Studio : The Android SDK Directory could not be found. Please set via /p:AndroidSdkDirectory

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xamarin-studio

I have installed Xamarin plugin for Visual Studio 2012.

And when create an Android Project and build the same. I am getting the following error.

**`Error    1   The Android SDK Directory could not be found. Please set via /p:AndroidSdkDirectory.    AndroidApplication1`**

I think this error is due to some mapping.

Kindly guide to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

You can also set the Android SDK location opening

```
Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings.
```

Or you have to re-install Android SDK.

Answer (score 7):

You can solve this by editing the build definition in the VS 2012.

Right click on the Build Definition and Edit Build Definition

Goto Process -> Advanced -> MSBuild Arguments and append the below parameter value to it

**/p:AndroidSdkDirectory=C:\android-sdk**

it should work.

Comment: Note also that if you're using a TFS build server, the build agent on the server runs in its own account, so the Android SDK and NDKs must be accessible to it. I saw this same error with the SDK/NDK installed in my user account AppData folder, which meant that a local build on the server worked fine, but the TFS build agent couldn't access it and thus failed. After I moved the SDK and NDK to an accessible place, everything worked. Alternately, you can set the account in the TFS admin console > Build Configuration > Build Service properties.

Comment: Also see Xamarin's Configuring TFS page (http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/configuring_tfs/) and also http://bzbetty.blogspot.com/2014/01/building-xamarin-applications-on-tfs.html.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have Visual Studio try to set Android SDK path to AndroidSdkDirectory environment variable.

For example I have Android SDK installed in */home/user1/.android-sdk-installer/android-sdk-linux*, so I set environment variable like this in terminal:

```
export AndroidSdkDirectory=/home/user1/.android-sdk-installer/android-sdk-linux
```

*Do not forget that export set environment variables only for current terminal.*

Also it's easier to set environment variable once, rather then pass /p:AndroidSdkDirectory every time you want to build.

Comment: This strategy also works for windows `SET AndroidSdkDirectory=c:\android-sdk` or via the widget to set it permanently.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution to this problem for me was to use vpn.since I live in a country where we are under internet boycott using vpn with some patience helped me a lot.
With best wishes...