# How to configure GitLab CI/CD for .NET 7 Maui (Android)

Tags: docker, .net-core, gitlab-ci, maui

I am a bit shocked Linux does not support building .NET MAUI apps unless they are

```
android                    .NET SDK Workload for building Android applications.
macos                      .NET SDK Workload for building macOS applications.  
maui-android               .NET MAUI SDK for Android                           
maui-tizen                 .NET MAUI SDK for Tizen                             
maui-windows               .NET MAUI SDK for Windows                           
runtimes-windows           Windows Runtime Packs                               
runtimes-windows-net6      Windows Runtime Packs                               
wasm-experimental          .NET WebAssembly experimental tooling               
wasm-tools                 .NET WebAssembly build tools                        
wasm-tools-net6            .NET WebAssembly build tools for net6.0
```

In any case, I'd like to know how do .NET Maui developers automate CI/CD in GitLab.
**Is there any built-in mechanism like there is in GitHub or Azure Pipelines? Or does it have to be configured manually? Could I see an example?**

This is what I've been trying so far, considering that the base image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0` won't be able to be used for certain platforms unfortunately..

I have created a custom Docker image. Let's call it dotnet-maui

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0

# Install workload maui
RUN dotnet workload search
RUN dotnet workload install android maui-android --ignore-failed-sources
```

**Is there any better alternative? Maybe an image that uses MacOs or windows where MAUI is supported?**

And now I use that image as the GitLab base image for my MAUI apps. Specifically for one that targets android only, but I am still unable to even compile..

```
dotnet build -f:net7.0-android -c:Release
```

throws an error

```
 dotnet build -f:net7.0-android -c:Release
MSBuild version 17.4.0+18d5aef85 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored /builds/roundev/roundev-easy-qr/src/EasyQr/EasyQr.csproj (in 16.86 sec).
/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Linux/33.0.4/tools/Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(70,5): error XA5300: The Android SDK directory could not be found. Check that the Android SDK Manager in Visual Studio shows a valid installation. To use a custom SDK path for a command line build, set the 'AndroidSdkDirectory' MSBuild property to the custom path. [/builds/roundev/roundev-easy-qr/src/EasyQr/EasyQr.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-android]
Build FAILED.
/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Linux/33.0.4/tools/Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(70,5): error XA5300: The Android SDK directory could not be found. Check that the Android SDK Manager in Visual Studio shows a valid installation. To use a custom SDK path for a command line build, set the 'AndroidSdkDirectory' MSBuild property to the custom path. [/builds/roundev/roundev-easy-qr/src/EasyQr/EasyQr.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-android]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:00.58
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

**How should I install and configure this Android SDK?**

PS: The fact that the errors show details about Visual Studio (which is a graphical user interface IDE) is a bit concerning.

---

### UPDATE 1 (2023-01-02)

I've attempted to build in Ubuntu 22.04 with CLI and I am having problems. The goal is to have all this automated in a Docker image.

First I install maui-android

```
dotnet workload install maui-android --ignore-failed-sources
```

Then I install Android SDK. 2 Options:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y android-sdk
```

or

```
sudo snap install androidsdk
```

Either way, the following attempt to build, fails

```
dotnet build -f net7.0-android /p:AndroidSdkDirectory=/usr/lib/android-sdk
```

with error about API level 33 not installed

```
MSBuild version 17.4.0+18d5aef85 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Linux/33.0.4/tools/Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(100,5): error XA5207: Could not find android.jar for API level 33. This means the Android SDK platform for API level 33 is not installed. Either install it in the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Open Android SDK Manager...), or change the Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is installed. (/usr/lib/android-sdk/platforms/android-33/android.jar missing.) [/media/diegosasw/data/src/roundev/roundev-easy-qr/src/EasyQr/EasyQr.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-android]
```

I have attempted to explicitly install API 33

```
yes | androidsdk "platform-tools" "platforms;android-33"
```

which creates a `~/AndroidSDK/platforms/android-33` with a jar inside

But

```
dotnet build -f net7.0-android /p:AndroidSdkDirectory=/home/diegosasw/AndroidSDK/platforms/android-33
```

also fails

```
MSBuild version 17.4.0+18d5aef85 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Linux/33.0.4/tools/Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(70,5): error XA5300: The Android SDK directory could not be found. Check that the Android SDK Manager in Visual Studio shows a valid installation. To use a custom SDK path for a command line build, set the 'AndroidSdkDirectory' MSBuild property to the custom path. [/media/diegosasw/data/src/roundev/roundev-easy-qr/src/EasyQr/EasyQr.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-android]
```

I would appreciate a working sample that I could use both locally in Linux Ubuntu, and in GitLab CI/CD

---

### UPDATE 2 (2023-01-02)

I got something working locally, but still unable to find a good solution for GitLab CI/CD (too large base image is causing problems)

I have the following *.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>MySample</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <EnableDefaultCssItems>false</EnableDefaultCssItems>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>MySample</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.roundev.mysample</ApplicationId>
        <ApplicationIdGuid>840AB3E3-0460-46FE-BDEA-94EEBB053DE2</ApplicationIdGuid>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">24.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
        <AndroidKeyStore>True</AndroidKeyStore>
        <AndroidSigningKeyStore>myapp.keystore</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
        <AndroidSigningKeyAlias>myalias</AndroidSigningKeyAlias>
        <AndroidSigningKeyPass></AndroidSigningKeyPass>
        <AndroidSigningStorePass></AndroidSigningStorePass>
    </PropertyGroup>


    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="7.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

#### At localhost (Ubuntu 22.04)

At localhost, I managed to compile and publish signed APK/AAB with following steps:

[image: Android SDK]
[image: SDK Tools]

Assuming SDK .NET 7 is already installed.

1. Install workload maui-android on the top of SDK .NET

   ```
   dotnet workload install maui-android --ignore-failed-sources
   ```
2. Installed Android SDK (Api level 33) through the Jetbrains Toolbox by installing Android Studio, with Android SDK build-tools also. Everything is under `/home/diegosasw/Android/Sdk`
3. Created keystore

   ```
   keytool -genkey -v -keystore myapp.keystore -alias myalias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 36500
   ```

   and entered password and details. The generated myapp.keystore, I place it at the same level as the `*.csproj` (Ideally it should not be versioned)
4. Compile

   ```
   dotnet build -f net7.0-android /p:AndroidSdkDirectory=/home/diegosasw/Android/Sdk
   ```
5. Publish

   ```
   dotnet publish -f:net7.0-android -c:Release -o dist /p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=<the_password> /p:AndroidSigningStorePass=<the_password> /p:AndroidSdkDirectory=/home/diegosasw/Android/Sdk
   ```

   and the `dist` folder will contain the AAB, signed AAB and signed APK.

The process for CI/CD automation would have to be similar, but with automated Android SDK installation, plus other tools,

#### At GitLab CI/CD

1. Firstly I create an image with the following `Dockerfile`. It's very heavy, and possibly it could be parametized, and greatly improved.

   ```
   ARG REPO=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet
   FROM $REPO:7.0.1-jammy-amd64 AS platform

   ENV \
       # Unset ASPNETCORE_URLS from aspnet base image
       ASPNETCORE_URLS= \
       # Do not generate certificate
       DOTNET_GENERATE_ASPNET_CERTIFICATE=false \
       # Do not show first run text
       DOTNET_NOLOGO=true \
       # SDK version
       DOTNET_SDK_VERSION=7.0.101 \
       # Enable correct mode for dotnet watch (only mode supported in a container)
       DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true \
       # Skip extraction of XML docs - generally not useful within an image/container - helps performance
       NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE=skip \
       # PowerShell telemetry for docker image usage
       POWERSHELL_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL=PSDocker-DotnetSDK-Ubuntu-22.04

   RUN apt-get update \
       && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
           curl \
           git \
           wget \
       && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

   # Install .NET SDK
   RUN curl -fSL --output dotnet.tar.gz https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/$DOTNET_SDK_VERSION/dotnet-sdk-$DOTNET_SDK_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz \
       && dotnet_sha512='cf289ad0e661c38dcda7f415b3078a224e8347528448429d62c0f354ee951f4e7bef9cceaf3db02fb52b5dd7be987b7a4327ca33fb9239b667dc1c41c678095c' \
       && echo "$dotnet_sha512  dotnet.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
       && mkdir -p /usr/share/dotnet \
       && tar -oxzf dotnet.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet ./packs ./sdk ./sdk-manifests ./templates ./LICENSE.txt ./ThirdPartyNotices.txt \
       && rm dotnet.tar.gz \
       # Trigger first run experience by running arbitrary cmd
       && dotnet help

   # Install PowerShell global tool
   RUN powershell_version=7.3.0 \
       && curl -fSL --output PowerShell.Linux.x64.$powershell_version.nupkg https://pwshtool.blob.core.windows.net/tool/$powershell_version/PowerShell.Linux.x64.$powershell_version.nupkg \
       && powershell_sha512='c4a72142e2bfae0c2a64a662f1baa27940f1db8a09384c90843163e339581d8d41824145fb9f79c680f9b7906043365e870d48d751ab8809c15a590f47562ae6' \
       && echo "$powershell_sha512  PowerShell.Linux.x64.$powershell_version.nupkg" | sha512sum -c - \
       && mkdir -p /usr/share/powershell \
       && dotnet tool install --add-source / --tool-path /usr/share/powershell --version $powershell_version PowerShell.Linux.x64 \
       && dotnet nuget locals all --clear \
       && rm PowerShell.Linux.x64.$powershell_version.nupkg \
       && ln -s /usr/share/powershell/pwsh /usr/bin/pwsh \
       && chmod 755 /usr/share/powershell/pwsh \
       # To reduce image size, remove the copy nupkg that nuget keeps.
       && find /usr/share/powershell -print | grep -i '.*[.]nupkg$' | xargs rm

   # JAVA
   RUN apt-get update && \
       apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk && \
       rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

   ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/

   # Install workload maui
   RUN dotnet workload install maui-android --ignore-failed-sources

   # Utils
   RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
       unzip \
       jq \
       bzip2 \
       libzip4 \
       libzip-dev && \
       rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

   # Install Android SDK
   RUN mkdir -p /usr/lib/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/latest && \
       curl -k "https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-9123335_latest.zip" -o commandlinetools-linux.zip && \
       unzip -q commandlinetools-linux.zip -d /usr/lib/android-sdk/tmp && \
       mv  /usr/lib/android-sdk/tmp/cmdline-tools/* /usr/lib/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/latest && \
       rm -rf /usr/lib/android-sdk/tmp/ && \
       rm commandlinetools-linux.zip 

   ENV ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/lib/android-sdk
   ENV PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:$PATH

   RUN yes | sdkmanager --licenses && \
       sdkmanager "platform-tools" && \
       sdkmanager "ndk-bundle" && \
       sdkmanager "build-tools;33.0.0" "platforms;android-33"
   ```
2. At the repo in GitLab, I create a secure file and upload the `myapp.keystore` (and I remove it from the filesystem).
3. At the repo in GitLab, I create a CI/CD environment variable `KEYSTORE_PASSWORD` with the password value
4. The idea is to have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` similar to this

   ```
   image: registry.gitlab.com/your_image_generated_out_of_Dockerfile:latest

   variables:
     PUBLISH_OUTPUT_DIR: dist
     ANDROID_SIGNING_KEY_PASS: $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
     ANDROID_SIGNING_STORE_PASS: $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD

   stages:
     - build
     - publish
     - delivery

   build:
     stage: build
     script:
       - dotnet build -f net7.0-android /p:AndroidSdkDirectory=/usr/lib/android-sdk 
     artifacts:
       paths:
         - test
       expire_in: 8 hour
     rules:
       - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG == null'

   publish_android:
     stage: publish
     variables:
       SECURE_FILES_DOWNLOAD_PATH: './'
     before_script:
       - APP_VERSION=$(cat ./version/semver)
       - curl --silent "https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/download-secure-files/-/raw/main/installer" | bash
     script:
       - dotnet publish 
         -f:net7.0-android 
         -c:Release 
         -o $PUBLISH_OUTPUT_DIR 
         /p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=$ANDROID_SIGNING_KEY_PASS 
         /p:AndroidSigningStorePass=$ANDROID_SIGNING_STORE_PASS 
         /p:AndroidSdkDirectory=/usr/lib/android-sdk 
         -p:Version=$APP_VERSION
     allow_failure: false
     artifacts:
       paths: 
         - $PUBLISH_OUTPUT_DIR/
       expire_in: 8 hour
     rules:
       - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
         when: on_success
       - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG == null'
   ```

   but unfortunately I cannot even generate the Docker image to use as base image because [I run out of space due to the huge image size I'm attempting to build](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/issues/1333#issuecomment-1369088515).

The question remains:

- Is there any easy/good way (working sample) to use GitLab CI/CD to build and publish AAB/APK with .NET 7 Maui targeting Android?
- Is there any official Docker image which I could directly use at GitLab CI for my `dotnet build` and `dotnet publish` of .NET 7 Maui projects (image with .NET 7 SDK, Android SDK, maui-android workload, JDK and other required tooling)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio : The Android SDK Directory could not be found. Please set via /p:AndroidSdkDirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078702/visual-studio-the-android-sdk-directory-could-not-be-found-please-set-via-p)

Comment: I'm afraid no... I know I will have to somehow install the Android SDK somewhere and pass that argument. I'm just wondering if there is any example on how to configure the whole pipeline to achieve this. 
With GitHub Actions it's extremely simple because it has built in tooling https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQuQPm40kys but for GitLab, every step needs to be explicit shell scripting and I haven't found any sample, nor any docker image which could have everything needed already available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got it working and with a smaller custom image built on the top of the "official" Microsoft's SDK .NET 7, without adding Android NDK (which I don't think it was needed).

This is my docker image

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0
MAINTAINER roundev

# JAVA
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/

# Install workload maui
RUN dotnet workload install maui-android --ignore-failed-sources

# Utils
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    unzip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Android SDK
RUN mkdir -p /usr/lib/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/latest && \
    curl -k "https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-9123335_latest.zip" -o commandlinetools-linux.zip && \
    unzip -q commandlinetools-linux.zip -d /usr/lib/android-sdk/tmp && \
    mv  /usr/lib/android-sdk/tmp/cmdline-tools/* /usr/lib/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/latest && \
    rm -rf /usr/lib/android-sdk/tmp/ && \
    rm commandlinetools-linux.zip 

ENV ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/lib/android-sdk
ENV PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:$PATH

RUN yes | sdkmanager --licenses && \
    sdkmanager "platform-tools" && \
    #sdkmanager "ndk-bundle" && \ # I Don't think this was needed at all
    sdkmanager "build-tools;33.0.0" "platforms;android-33"
```

This, generated and stored in GitLab container registry, takes "only" 2.5GB.

So now the pipeline is successful with this .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: registry.gitlab.com/roundev/devops/dotnet-maui:latest

variables:
  PUBLISH_OUTPUT_DIR: dist
  ANDROID_SIGNING_KEY_PASS: $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
  ANDROID_SIGNING_STORE_PASS: $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD

stages:
  - build
  - publish
  - delivery

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - dotnet build -f net7.0-android /p:AndroidSdkDirectory=/usr/lib/android-sdk 
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG == null'

publish_android:
  stage: publish
  variables:
    SECURE_FILES_DOWNLOAD_PATH: './'
  before_script:
    - curl --silent "https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/download-secure-files/-/raw/main/installer" | bash
  script:
    - dotnet publish 
      -f:net7.0-android 
      -c:Release 
      -o $PUBLISH_OUTPUT_DIR 
      /p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=$ANDROID_SIGNING_KEY_PASS 
      /p:AndroidSigningStorePass=$ANDROID_SIGNING_STORE_PASS 
      /p:AndroidSdkDirectory=/usr/lib/android-sdk
  allow_failure: false
  artifacts:
    paths: 
      - $PUBLISH_OUTPUT_DIR/
    expire_in: 8 hour
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
      when: on_success
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG == null'
```

Notice it is using a secure file where I upload my `myapp.keystore`
and a CI/CD variable `KEYSTORE_PASSWORD` with the signing key pass and store pass (it's the same in my case).

Comment: I get a `Workload ID maui-android isn't supported on this platform.` when trying to run `RUN dotnet workload install maui-android --ignore-failed-sources` - what am I doing wrong?